# Xorg xorgxrdp update

Tags: centos

update xrdp and xorgxrd on Centos 7.5.1804 ,  turns around on the outbuildings.

currently in xorgxrdp.x86_64 0: 0.2.8-1.el7 and xrdp.x86_64 1:0.9.8-1.el7 xorg-x11-server-Xorg (x86-64) = 1.20.1 for the package: xorgxrdp-0.2.8-3.el7.x86_64
Processing Dependency: xrdp-selinux = 1: 0.9.8-2.el7 for package: 1: xrdp-0.9.8-2.el7.x86_64
How to get out of this blocking situation
The solution  yum --enablerepo = cr seems risky and premature!(possible system instability !)

Comment: Probably you will need to file a bug report but it does not appear you have posted the full command and output. Also what repos do you ha e enabled

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, temporarily using the CR repo is the best you can do.  The updates to xrdp in EPEL rely on packages released in RHEL but haven’t hit main repos in CentOS yet.